# как одновременно создать БД и таблицу?

Tags: php, mysql

```php
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = "root";
$password = '';
$dbname = 'MySQLLesson';


$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);


if(!$conn){
    die("CONNECT ERROR ". mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = 'CREATE DATABASE MySQLLesson';


if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    echo "DATABASE NAMED AS ".$dbname." HAS BEEN CREATED";
}else{
    echo "ERROR ". mysqli_error($conn);
}

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE users(
        name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        surname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        password VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    )";
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Знаете, сама задача порочна: обычно так не делают. База создаётся единожды при развёртывании, да и таблицы из миграций. Ну а совмещать -- вообще моветон.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = 'MySQLLesson';

$dbh = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

if ($dbh->connect_error) {
    die($dbh->connect_error);
}

if (!$dbh->query("CREATE DATABASE `".$dbname."`")) {
    die($dbh->error);    
} 

if (!$dbh->select_db($db_name)){
    die($dbh->error);
}

$sql = "CREATE TABLE users(
        id INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        surname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        password VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL)";

if(!$dbh->query($sql)){
    die($dbh->error);
}

$dbh->close();
```